# update statement with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Good day everyone..!:-)

I have this table `tab` where `totalUsed`  is equal to the sum of all `used` values referenced to `name`

```
cid         name                used            total
1           a                   1               1
2           a                   3               4
3           a                   6               10
4           b                   3               3
5           b                   7               10
6           b                   10              0
7           a                   5               0
```

i have this code but it only copy totalUsed's  adjacent `used` value

```
UPDATE tab
    SET totalUsed=
(
    SELECT SUM(used)
)



cid         name                used            total
1           a                   1               1
2           a                   3               3
3           a                   6               6
4           b                   3               3
5           b                   7               7
6           b                   10              10
7           a                   5               5
```

if `used` is set as 10 for `cid` 6, `totalUsed` should be 20
and for `cid` 7 it should be 15.
how to do it in mysql?

it should look like this.

```
cid         name                used            total
1           a                   1               1
2           a                   3               4
3           a                   6               10
4           b                   3               3
5           b                   7               10
6           b                   10              20
7           a                   5               15
```

thanks for help
:-)

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Im not sure about sql engine is..but I think it was something like XAMPP? which am i using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most dialects of SQL, you can do this using an `update` with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tab
    SET totalUsed = (SELECT SUM(used)
                     from tab tab2
                     where tab2.name = tab.name and
                           tab2.cid <= tab.cid
                    );
```

EDIT:

The above will not work in MySQL.  You can do this instead:

```
UPDATE tab join
       (select tab2.cid,
               (SELECT SUM(used)
                from tab tab3
                where tab3.name = tab2.name and
                      tab3.cid <= tab2.cid
               ) as cum_used
        from tab tab2
       ) tab2
       on tab.cid = tab2.cid
    SET tab.totalUsed = tab2.cum_used;
```

Comment: Sir this sql statement produces this error

[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'tab' for update in FROM clause